# How elaborate more an intermediate event via a C# function invocation?

Tags: esper, nesper

I'm novice in NESPER, and in some point of my application (stm-A), I need to use a function in C# that transform the original event in (possible) several different events (the original one enriched, and possibly additional events)

I think that a possible approach would be to create a listener for (stm-A), invoke the function and then inject the new events again to the engine.

This is right? There is a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at User Defined Functions (http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.2.0/esper-reference/html/functionreference.html#epl-function-user-defined and here: http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.2.0/esper-reference/html/extension.html#custom-singlerow-function).

The documentation is for Java, but the same principle applies to .Net and Nesper. You'll need to "tell" Nesper about the function (via configuration) and then just call it directly from your EPL.